# a startdocprinter call was not issued OnEndPrint

Tags: c#, printing

I have a C# Windows application that was printing correctly. I made some changes by moving some things around. I performed some unit testing in my dev environment. Compiled and installed on a win 7 pc. I am now getting the following error from the compiled version. I did some google searching and all I could find was some XP problems. Search on here and found some VBA problems, none of which applies to me. I can post some code if need be. Kinda stumped right now.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): A StartDocPrinter call was not issued
   at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnEndPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnEndPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
   at TPG.Printing.PrintPickTicket(String OrdNum, Boolean blnReprint, Boolean blnSwapOrder)
   at TPG.frmPrintTicket.btnReprint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

My Code

```
public void PrintPickTicket(string OrdNum, bool blnReprint, bool blnSwapOrder)
{
    UserBusiness userBiz = new UserBusiness();
    OrderBusiness OrderBus = new OrderBusiness();
    UserPrinterSetting setting = userBiz.GetUserPrinterSettings(SessionHelper.UserData.UserID, MachineName);
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = setting.DocumentPrinter;  
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    blnDetailRecs = false;
    blnNotesRecs = false;
    blnSwapRecs = false;
    blnIsReprint = blnReprint;
    blnIsSwapOrder = blnSwapOrder;

    //
    //Get the data needed to print a pick ticket
    //

    //Pick Ticket Header, Merchant Info, 
    dsOrders = OrderBus.GetPickTicketInfo(OrdNum);
    dsMerchDetails = OrderBus.GetMerchantInfo(OrdNum);
    dsOrderDetails = OrderBus.GetPickDetailsInfo(OrdNum);
    dsComments = OrderBus.GetLineItemComments(OrdNum);
    dsShipComments = OrderBus.GetShippingComments(OrdNum);
    dsSwap = OrderBus.GetSwapOrder(OrdNum.TrimEnd() + 'S');

    if (dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        blnIsSwapOrder = true;
    }

    //Initialize printing vars
    sopNumber = OrdNum.TrimEnd();
    sStatus = "Detail";
    pgCnt = 1;
    rCnt = 0;
    rSCnt = 0;
    rCCnt = 0;

    //Print the doggone thing already
    pd.Print();

    //Clean up your crap dammit
    dsShipComments.Dispose();

    if (blnIsSwapOrder)
    {
        dsSwap.Dispose();
    }

    dsOrderDetails.Dispose();
    dsMerchDetails.Dispose();
    dsOrders.Dispose();
    dsComments.Dispose();
    dsShipComments.Dispose();
}

private static string GetNumbers(string input)
{
    return new string(input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush blkBrush = Brushes.Black;
    Brush gryBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
    Pen gryPen = new Pen(Color.DarkGray);
    Font hdrFont = new Font("Arial Black", 10, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Font hdrsmFont = new Font("Arial Black", 7, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Font dtlFont = new Font("Arial", 10, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Font ttlFont = new Font("Arial Black", 12, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Font bcFont = new Font("Free 3 of 9 Extended", 24, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Font bcSmallFont = new Font("Free 3 of 9 Extended", 16, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    int LinesPerPage = 20;
    int intLineCnt = 0;
    string lineComment = "";
    string printComment = "";
    string rmaNumber = "";

    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;

    System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
    string theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    Bitmap lgoImage = new Bitmap(theDirectory + @"\Images\phxLetr.png");

    //
    //
    // Print Page Heading
    //
    //
    g.DrawImage(lgoImage, 5, 5);
    g.DrawString("Page ", dtlFont, blkBrush, 194, 7);
    g.DrawString(pgCnt.ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 206, 7);
    g.DrawString("Enter Date:", dtlFont, blkBrush, 190, 11);
    g.DrawString("Print Date:", dtlFont, blkBrush, 190, 15);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EntDate"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 208, 11);
    g.DrawString(now.ToString("g"), dtlFont, blkBrush, 208, 15);

    if (sStatus == "Detail" || sStatus == "Swap")
    {
        g.DrawString("PICK TICKET", ttlFont, blkBrush, 47, 7);

        if (blnIsSwapOrder)
        {
            g.DrawString("*SWAP*", ttlFont, blkBrush, 85, 7);
        }

        g.DrawString("Picked By:    _____________", hdrFont, blkBrush, 60, 15);
        g.DrawString("Inspect By:   _____________", hdrFont, blkBrush, 60, 25);
        g.DrawString("Observe By:  _____________", hdrFont, blkBrush, 120, 15);
        g.DrawString("Deploy By:    _____________", hdrFont, blkBrush, 120, 25);
    }
    else if (sStatus == "Notes")
    {
        g.DrawString("DEPLOYMENT INFO", ttlFont, blkBrush, 47, 7);
    }

    if (sStatus != "Swap")
    {
        g.DrawString('*' + sopNumber + '*', bcFont, blkBrush, 207, 20);
        g.DrawString(sopNumber, dtlFont, blkBrush, 215, 27);
    }
    else
    {
        g.DrawString('*' + sopNumber + 'S' + '*', bcFont, blkBrush, 207, 20);
        g.DrawString(sopNumber + "S", dtlFont, blkBrush, 215, 27);
    }

    if (blnIsReprint)
    {
        g.DrawString("****  REPRINT  ****", dtlFont, blkBrush, 215, 7);
    }

    //
    //Bill To Box
    //
    g.DrawRectangle(gryPen, 3, 43, 85, 23);  //Bill To box
    g.DrawString("Bill To:", hdrFont, blkBrush, 3, 38);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 20, 39);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString().Substring(0, 31), dtlFont, blkBrush, 5, 45);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerAddress1"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 5, 50);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerAddress2"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 5, 55);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerCity"].ToString().TrimEnd() + ", " + 
                dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerState"].ToString().TrimEnd() + " " + 
                dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerZip"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 5, 60);

    //
    //Ship To Box
    //
    g.DrawRectangle(gryPen, 92, 43, 85, 23);  //Ship To box
    g.DrawString("Ship To:", hdrFont, blkBrush, 92, 38);

    if (sStatus == "Swap")
    {
        g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SwapShipToName"].ToString().Substring(0, 31), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 45);
        g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SwapShippingAddress1"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 50);
        g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SwapShippingAddress2"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 55);
        g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SwapShippingCity"].ToString().TrimEnd() + ", " +
                    dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SwapShippingState"].ToString().TrimEnd() + " " +
                    dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SwapShippingZip"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 60);
    }
    else
    {
        g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShipToName"].ToString().Substring(0, 31), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 45);

        if (!blnIsSwapOrder)
        {
            g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShippingAddress1"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 50);
            g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShippingAddress2"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 55);
            g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShippingCity"].ToString().TrimEnd() + ", " +
                        dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShippingState"].ToString().TrimEnd() + " " +
                        dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShippingZip"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 60);
        }
    }

    //
    //Merch Info box
    //
    g.DrawRectangle(gryPen, 185, 33, 83, 33);  
    g.DrawString("M", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 35);
    g.DrawString("E", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 38);
    g.DrawString("R", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 41);
    g.DrawString("C", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 44);
    g.DrawString("H", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 47);
    g.DrawString("I", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 53);
    g.DrawString("N", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 56);
    g.DrawString("F", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 59);
    g.DrawString("O", hdrsmFont, blkBrush, 181, 62);

    if (dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        g.DrawString(dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MID"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 187, 35);
        g.DrawString(dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustName"].ToString().Substring(0, 30), dtlFont, blkBrush, 187, 40);
        g.DrawString(dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address1"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 187, 45);
        g.DrawString(dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address2"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 187, 50);
        g.DrawString(dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["City"].ToString().TrimEnd() + ", " +
                    dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["State"].ToString().TrimEnd() + " " +
                    dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Zip"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 187, 55);
        g.DrawString(dsMerchDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 187, 60);
    }

    //
    //Purch Order, Ship Mthd, etc.  box
    //
    g.DrawRectangle(gryPen, 3, 68, 265, 18); 
    g.DrawString("Purchase Order", hdrFont,blkBrush, 5, 70);
    g.DrawString("Shipping Method", hdrFont, blkBrush, 46, 70);
    g.DrawString("Shipper Number", hdrFont, blkBrush, 90, 70);
    g.DrawString("Ship Notes: ", hdrFont, blkBrush, 133, 70);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CStponbr"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 5, 75);
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShippingMethod"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 47, 75); 
    g.DrawString(dsOrders.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShipperNumber"].ToString().TrimEnd(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 94, 75);

    //if (ShipNum.Length > 23)
    //{
    //    ShipNum = ShipNum.Substring(0, 24);
    //}

    if (dsShipComments.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
        g.DrawString(dsShipComments.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Comment_1"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 161, 70);
        g.DrawString(dsShipComments.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Comment_2"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 161, 74);
        g.DrawString(dsShipComments.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Comment_3"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 161, 78);
        g.DrawString(dsShipComments.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Comment_4"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 161, 82);
    }

    //
    //Detail Header and Data
    //
    if (sStatus == "Detail" || sStatus == "Swap")
    {                
        g.DrawString("Item Num", hdrFont, blkBrush, 3, 90);
        g.DrawString("Desc", hdrFont, blkBrush, 70, 90);
        g.DrawString("Inv", hdrFont, blkBrush, 190, 86); 
        g.DrawString("Bin", hdrFont, blkBrush, 190, 90);
        g.DrawString("Pick", hdrFont, blkBrush, 219, 86);
        g.DrawString("Qty", hdrFont, blkBrush, 219, 90);
        g.DrawString("UOM", hdrFont, blkBrush, 234, 90);
        g.DrawString("QC", hdrFont, blkBrush, 248, 90);
    }
    else if (sStatus == "Notes")
    {
        g.DrawString("Qty", hdrFont, blkBrush, 3, 90);
        g.DrawString("Item Num", hdrFont, blkBrush, 13, 90);
        g.DrawString("Deployment Info", hdrFont, blkBrush, 80, 90);
    }

    //
    //Details Data
    //
    int ypos = 95;
    int count = 0;
    Boolean blnShadow = false;

    if (sStatus == "Detail")
    {
        while (count < LinesPerPage && rCnt < dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        {
            if (blnShadow)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(gryBrush, 3, ypos, 265, 5);
            }

            g.DrawString(dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows[rCnt]["ITEMNMBR"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 3, ypos);
            g.DrawString(dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows[rCnt]["ITEMDESC"].ToString().Substring(0, 60), dtlFont, blkBrush, 70, ypos);
            g.DrawString(dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows[rCnt]["LOCNCODE"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 190, ypos);
            g.DrawString(string.Format("{0:0}", (dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows[rCnt]["QUANTITY"])), dtlFont, blkBrush, 218, ypos);
            g.DrawString(dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows[rCnt]["UOFM"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 234, ypos);                   
            ypos = ypos + 5;
            rCnt ++;
            intLineCnt ++;
            count ++;
            blnShadow = !blnShadow;
        }

        if (rCnt <= dsOrderDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count && intLineCnt >= LinesPerPage) 
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            pgCnt ++;
            intLineCnt = 0;
            ypos = 95;
            blnDetailRecs = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            pgCnt ++;
            blnDetailRecs = false;
        }
    }

    //
    //Deployment page details
    //
    if (sStatus == "Notes")
    {
        ypos = 95;
        count = 0;
        blnShadow = false;

        if (dsComments.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            g.DrawString("****  NO INFORMATION  ****", dtlFont, blkBrush, 70, ypos);
        }

        while (count < LinesPerPage && rCCnt < dsComments.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        {
            if (blnShadow)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(gryBrush, 3, ypos, 265, 5);
            }

            lineComment = dsComments.Tables[0].Rows[rCCnt]["cmtText"].ToString().TrimEnd();
            g.DrawString(string.Format("{0:0}", (dsComments.Tables[0].Rows[rCCnt]["QUANTITY"])), dtlFont, blkBrush, 3, ypos);
            g.DrawString(dsComments.Tables[0].Rows[rCCnt]["ITEMNMBR"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 13, ypos);

            if (dsComments.Tables[0].Rows[rCCnt]["ITEMNMBR"].ToString().StartsWith("CALL TAG"))
            {
                rmaNumber = GetNumbers(dsComments.Tables[0].Rows[rCCnt]["cmtText"].ToString().TrimEnd());
                rmaNumber = "RMA" + rmaNumber.PadLeft(12, '0');
                g.DrawString(rmaNumber, dtlFont, blkBrush, 80, ypos);
                g.DrawString("*" + rmaNumber + "*", bcSmallFont, blkBrush, 130, ypos);
                ypos = ypos + 5;
                blnShadow = !blnShadow;
                intLineCnt++;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                //if the comment is really long then wrap that rascal
                if (Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(lineComment.Length) / 90) > 1)
                {
                    if (count + (Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(lineComment.Length) / 90)) > LinesPerPage)
                    {
                        //Force new page before printing
                        count = LinesPerPage;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (lineComment.Length > 0)
                        {
                            if (lineComment.Length > 90)
                            {
                                printComment = lineComment.Substring(1, 90);
                                lineComment = lineComment.Substring(91);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printComment = lineComment;
                                lineComment = "";
                            }

                            if (blnShadow)
                            {
                                g.FillRectangle(gryBrush, 3, ypos, 265, 5);
                            }

                            g.DrawString(printComment, dtlFont, blkBrush, 80, ypos);
                            ypos = ypos + 5;
                            blnShadow = !blnShadow;
                            intLineCnt++;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawString(lineComment, dtlFont, blkBrush, 80, ypos);
                    intLineCnt++;
                    count++;
                    ypos = ypos + 5;
                    blnShadow = !blnShadow;
                }
            }

            rCCnt = rCCnt + 1;                    
        }

        if (rCCnt <= dsComments.Tables[0].Rows.Count && intLineCnt >= LinesPerPage)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            pgCnt++;
            intLineCnt = 0;
            ypos = 95;
            blnNotesRecs = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (blnIsSwapOrder)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                blnNotesRecs = false;
                pgCnt++;
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
                blnNotesRecs = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //
    //Swap page details
    //
    if (sStatus == "Swap")
    {
        ypos = 95;
        count = 0;
        blnShadow = false;

        while (count < LinesPerPage && rSCnt < dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        {
            if (blnShadow)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(gryBrush, 3, ypos, 265, 5);
            }

            g.DrawString(dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["ITEMNMBR"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 3, ypos);

            if (dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["ITEMNMBR"].ToString().StartsWith("CALL TAG"))
            {
                rmaNumber = GetNumbers(dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["ITEMDESC"].ToString().TrimEnd());
                rmaNumber = "RMA" + rmaNumber.PadLeft(12, '0');
                g.DrawString(rmaNumber, dtlFont, blkBrush, 70, ypos);
                g.DrawString("*" + rmaNumber + "*", bcSmallFont, blkBrush, 120, ypos);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawString(dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["ITEMDESC"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 70, ypos);
            }

            g.DrawString(dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["LOCNCODE"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 190, ypos);
            g.DrawString(string.Format("{0:0}", dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["QUANTITY"]), dtlFont, blkBrush, 218, ypos); 
            g.DrawString(dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows[rSCnt]["UOFM"].ToString(), dtlFont, blkBrush, 234, ypos);                    
            ypos = ypos + 5;
            rSCnt++;
            intLineCnt++;
            count++;
            blnShadow = !blnShadow;
        }

        if (rSCnt <= dsSwap.Tables[0].Rows.Count && intLineCnt >= LinesPerPage)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            pgCnt++;
            intLineCnt = 0;
            ypos = 95;
            blnSwapRecs = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            pgCnt++;
            blnSwapRecs = false;
        }
    }

    switch (sStatus)
    {
        case "Detail":
            if (!blnDetailRecs)
                {sStatus = "Notes";}
                break;
        case "Notes":
            if (!blnNotesRecs)
                {sStatus = "Swap";}
                break;
        case "Swap":
            if (!blnSwapRecs)
                {sStatus = "Detail";}
                break;
    }
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, you should post your code in your question so we can further help you with your problem. Just seeing the exception is not as helpful as seeing the code alongside the exception.

Comment: I attached my code to the original question

Comment: The StandardPrintController class has a bug, it does not properly deal with failure of the EndDocPrinter() winapi function.  It assumes that this function sets the last error code, but MSDN doesn't fail to point out that it doesn't.  So you cannot trust the error message and you can be 100% sure that StartDocPrinter() in fact has been called.  Printer drivers that generate errors but don't otherwise pop up a message that says what went wrong (out of toner, out of paper, etcetera) are pretty hard to deal with.  Try another one.

Comment: This occurs on every printer I have, even a pdf.

Comment: This can also happen if you ported [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.createstreamcallback.aspx) example to a class (for reuse) and called the same instance more than once for RDLC rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I ran the application as Administrator and it I was given a different error. The error indicated a problem with the bitmap being printed. It could not find the bitmap. Apparently our installation procedures did not include the associated images folder.